# NumberDecimal InputType with "Next" button

Tags: android, custom-controls, android-softkeyboard

When a standard EditText has focus the softkeyboard shows a "Next" button to move the the next field (It does on my Nexus 4 at least) but if I have an EditText with `inputType="numberDecimal"` the keyboard instad shows a "return" icon. Is there anyway to force the keyboard to always show the "Next" button?

Just to clarify, I want the "Next" button available to move focus to the next available `EditText` on the screen once user input is completed for the particular field.

Example with "Next" button;

[image: Keyboard with "Next" button]

Example without "Next" button;

[image: Keyboard without "Next" button]

Comment: If input type is numberDecimal, Why would you want it to enter other characters?

Comment: I want to move focus to the next available `EditText` once user input has finished.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you added

```
android:imeOptions="actionNext"
```

in your EditText.

For those, If above not working while using in number mode you can still use :

```
 android:nextFocusDown="@+id/parentedit"
```

where parentedit is the ID of the next EditText to be focused.

Comment: This is not working for me. On the standard EditText it works, but when I switch to numbers, it stops working.

Comment: @JitenderDev I solved it. The problem was in the Numbers Keyboard xml. I had an attribute `android:keyEdgeFlags="left"` on the key near the **Next** button. So it was "stealing" the click on the Next. So i just needed to delete that attribute